# How to match anything between < & > in regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I'm trying to match anything that lies between < and >, and nothing seems to be working.

My current code is:

```
    var regex = /\<(.*?)\>/
    var targeting = $('#auto-expand').val     //A text area
    function validateText(field)
    {
        if (regex.test(field) == true)
            {
                alert(field.match(regex))
            }
        else
            {
                alert("fail")
            }
    }
```

It keeps returning fail, not sure why.
Any help would be so great! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question how you are calling the `validateText` function. But it looks like are trying to set `targeting` outside the function, which means you are probably setting it before there's text in the box.

Below I change `val` to `val()` to call the function and looked up the value when the function runs rather than before. The regex itself works fine ([keeping this in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454))

```js
var regex = /<(.*?)>/

function validateText() {
  var targeting = $('#auto-expand').val() //A text area

  if (regex.test(targeting) == true) {
    alert(targeting.match(regex))
  } else {
    alert("fail")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="auto-expand"></textarea>
<button onclick=validateText()>Test</button>
```

Comment: Well spotted. And kudos for the golden link at the end!

Comment: Haven't seen a Zalgo link in so long - I read it every time too, it's classic, and I want the t-shirt :p